# How can you short more shares than what is available?

Tags: shorting-securities

I'm trying to wrap my head around the recent events of [NYSE:GME](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GME/key-statistics?p=GME), that [quote](https://www.fool.com/investing/2021/01/27/short-squeezes-everything-you-need-to-know-about-t/) the *short interest* to be `140.3%`. I have not been able to find any satisfactory explanation as to how this is possible or calculated. Especially since most sources simply state that:

> *Short interest is a measure of the number of shares that are currently being shorted compared to the number of tradable shares in the market (the float).*

[image]

---

**How can you short more shares than what is available?**

---

**UPDATE**: 2021-02-01

I've since found some relevant info that relates to how large hedge funds *can* force stocks into pennies and eventually zero. It explains in more detail how the (shorted) stock borrowing scheme is working.

- [The Anatomy of A Short Attack](https://seekingalpha-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/seekingalpha.com/amp/instablog/11442671-gerald-klein/3096735-anatomy-of-a-short-attack?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQHKAFQArABIA%3D%3D#ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fseekingalpha.com%2Finstablog%2F11442671-gerald-klein%2F3096735-anatomy-of-a-short-attack)
- [Counterfeiting Stock 2.0](http://counterfeitingstock.com/CS2.0/CounterfeitingStock.html)

<sub>DISCLAIMER: I am not able to determine the veracity of this info.</sub>

---

Other Related Questions:

- [How can GameStop be short 140% of float?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135446/how-can-gamestop-be-short-140-of-float)
- [question about short selling stocks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63140/question-about-short-selling-stocks?rq=1)
- [What are the implications for GameStop as a company in the aftermath of the current share price surge?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135583/what-are-the-implications-for-gamestop-as-a-company-in-the-aftermath-of-the-curr?rq=1)
- [What is the actual reason the short sellers of GME can't just hold their positions until the price goes back to normal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135599/what-is-the-actual-reason-the-short-sellers-of-gme-cant-just-hold-their-positio?rq=1)
- [Can a single share of stock be shorted multiple times?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126685/can-a-single-share-of-stock-be-shorted-multiple-times)
- [Can someone explain the GME short squeeze situation to a non-stock trader?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135411/can-someone-explain-the-gme-short-squeeze-situation-to-a-non-stock-trader)

Comment: The math works out for `Short % of Shares Outstanding` but I have yet to understand where `Short % of Float (226.42)` comes from.  61.78M short shares divided by 226.42% is 27.28M and I don't see that number in the stats.

Comment: After having looked at the added links, I think that the number of *borrowed* shares are simply an estimate based on possibly (near inside) information. Highlighting the issue with the current lack of more detailed *shorting* regulations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easily.**

Let's assume there's a company that has 1 share. That's right, whoever has the share owns the entire company.

The original shareholder loans the share to a borrower.

The borrower then sells the share without telling the original shareholder. Thus, the borrower has to buy the share back later because it's borrowed and the loan must be re-paid.

Somebody purchases the sold share.

The person who purchased the sold share loans the share to borrower #2.

The borrower #2 then sells the share without telling the purchaser. Thus, the borrower #2 has to buy the share back later because it's borrowed and the loan must be re-paid.

Somebody else purchases the share sold a second time.

Now you have a structure where the only share of the company is shorted twice. That's 200% short interest.

Comment: That's crazy! :) So how do you see this in the company stats shown (in my picture) above? I mean what are the *ingredients* needed in order to calculate the correct *short interest* percentage.

Comment: If that blows your mind, read up on how the US Dollar works!